# How do I get my contribution form fields on the same line

Tags: joomla, forms, css, bootstrap

I have bootstrap Joomla theme and it is changing the format of form fields. I understand that this is a CSS issue but my question is how can I get my live contribution page to look like the test page within civicrm?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your website looks like you figured out the CSS needed to match the test sample. Well done.

Answer (score 1):

I'm still finding my way around civicrm so it looks like no style was applied to civicrm or the template css file takes precedence. I used some of the style setting from civicrm.css in the custom css section of the template and this fixed the issue. There is problem a cleaner way to use the civicrm style sheet but for now this worked for me.